# Webgl: alternative to writing to gl_FragDepth

Tags: glsl, webgl, raytracing, fragment-shader, depth-buffer

In WebGL, is it possible to write to the fragment's depth value or control the fragment's depth value in some other way?

As far as I could find, gl_FragDepth is not present in webgl 1.x, but I am wondering if there is any other way (extensions, browser specific support, etc) to do it.

What I want to archive is to have a ray traced object play along with other elements drawn using the usual model, view, projection.

Comment: You can manipulate depth value in vertex shader like this `gl_Position.z = x * 2.0 - 1.0` where `x` in `[0,1]` (or `[-1,1]` without `* 2.0 - 1.0`)... But this will work if `gl_Position.w=1.0`...

Comment: @andre No solution for this yet?

Comment: @ViktorSehr looks like some browsers now implement the extension. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the extension [`EXT_frag_depth`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/EXT_frag_depth/)

Because it's an extension it might not be available everywhere so you need to check it exists.

```
var isFragDepthAvailable = gl.getExtension("EXT_frag_depth");
```

If `isFragDepthAvailable` is not falsey then you can enable it in your shaders with

```
#extension GL_EXT_frag_depth : enable
```

Otherwise you can manipulate `gl_Position.z` in your vertex shader though I suspect that's not really a viable solution for most needs.

Answer (score 3):

Brad Larson has a clever workaround for this that he uses in Molecules ([full blog post](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2011/05/08/enhancing-molecules-using-opengl-es-20)):

> To work around this, I implemented my own custom depth buffer using a
>   frame buffer object that was bound to a texture the size of the
>   screen. For each frame, I first do a rendering pass where the only
>   value that is output is a color value corresponding to the depth at
>   that point. In order to handle multiple overlapping objects that might
>   write to the same fragment, I enable color blending and use the
>   GL_MIN_EXT blending equation. This means that the color components
>   used for that fragment (R, G, and B) are the minimum of all the
>   components that objects have tried to write to that fragment (in my
>   coordinate system, a depth of 0.0 is near the viewer, and 1.0 is far
>   away). In order to increase the precision of depth values written to
>   this texture, I encode depth to color in such a way that as depth
>   values increase, red fills up first, then green, and finally blue.
>   This gives me 768 depth levels, which works reasonably well.

EDIT: Just realized WebGL doesn't support min blending, so not very useful.  Sorry.