# Using gl_FragDepth in WebGL

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

I am writing a 3D application in webgl, and need to provide my own depth data that is contained within a texture, my current code does this:

VS:

```
    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main() {
        vUv = uv;
    }
```

FS:

```
    uniform sampler2D depthTex;

    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main() {
        gl_FragDepth = texture2D(depthTex, vUv).r;
    }
```

however `gl_FragDepth` is disabled in opengl-es (and therefor webgl) is there anyway to somehow enable it, or any way to provide my own depth data that doesnt involve heavy manipulation of render targets?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101017/webgl-alternative-to-writing-to-gl-fragdepth

Answer (score 5):

The [EXT_frag_depth extension](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/EXT_frag_depth/) enables the use of gl_FragDepthEXT. You can check if your browser supports it [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/tests/conformance/extensions/ext-frag-depth.html). At the moment it's only supported in Firefox.

The extension can be loaded using

```
gl.getExtension("EXT_frag_depth");
```

And you can check if it is available programatically using

```
gl.getSupportedExtensions().indexOf("EXT_frag_depth") >= 0
```

Answer (score 2):

WebGL2 supports `gl_FragDepth` as core functionality, and the previously mentioned `EXT_frag_depth` extension is therefore no longer available for WebGL2.