# Is it possible to change the depth of each fragment when using 'gl.PointCoord'?

Tags: glsl, webgl

I want to know how can I adjust the depth value of each fragment (using `gl_FragDepth`). I render point primitives with `gl_PointSize=5.0`.

I know that in fragment shader, I can access to each fragment via gl.PointCoord.xy, but i failed to reset different depth values to each fragment?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: when using point primitives, all fragements of this point have the same depth value, i want to adjust depth value and give different depth value to each fragment of this point. when i use gl_fragDepth i get this error: gl_fragDepth undeclared identifier. ??? what is the problem

Comment: Yes, i know is exactly what i did but, is it work with point primitives or only with triangle primitives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WebGL 1.0 the extension `EXT_frag_depth` has to be enabeld to access [`gl_FragDepth`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/gl_FragDepth.xhtml):

- [WebGL EXT_frag_depth Khronos Ratified Extension Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/EXT_frag_depth/)
- Stackoverflow question [Using gl_FragDepth in WebGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499321/using-gl-fragdepth-in-webgl)

You can write to the built in uniform [`out float gl_FragDepth;`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/gl_FragDepth.xhtml) in the fragment shader. The value of [`gl_FragDepth`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/gl_FragDepth.xhtml) is set to the depth buffer. Since the depth is set in the fragment shader it affects a single fragment.

The valid range for the depth is set by [`glDepthRange`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glDepthRangef.xhtml). By default the depth range is from 0 to 1. 0 is near and 1 is far.

If [`gl_FragDepth`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/gl_FragDepth.xhtml) is not set, then the `z` component of [`gl_FragCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml) will be set to the depth buffer.

The depth of a vertex position of a primitve (in your case a point) is specified by setting the `z` component of [`gl_Position`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/gl_Position.xhtml) in the vertex shader. If `-gl_Position.w < gl_Position.z` and `gl_Position.z < gl_Position.w` then the depth (`z` component) is in the clip space.

Th clip space coordinate is transformed to the normalized device space coordinate by dividing by the `w` component of [`gl_Position`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/gl_Position.xhtml) (perspective divide, beacause [`gl_Position`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/gl_Position.xhtml) is a [Homogeneous coordinat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates)). So the `z` components, between the near and the far plane of the normalized device space, are in the range [-1, 1].

Finally the `z` component of the normalized device space (in range [-1, 1]) is mapped to the depth range, which is by default in [0, 1].

Note, [`in mediump vec2 gl_PointCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/gl_PointCoord.xhtml) is 2 dimensional input variable to the fragment shader. You cannot write to it.

See [OpenGL ES Shading Language 1.00 Specification, 7.2 Fragment Shader Special Variables, page 60](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf):

> The fragment shader has access to the read-only built-in variable gl_PointCoord. The values in `gl_PointCoord` are two-dimensional coordinates indicating where within a point primitive the current fragment is located. They range from 0.0 to 1.0 across the point.

Comment: thanks for the reply, what if i do the rendering in floating textures and i change the depth of each fragment of the point manually? I get different values for each fragment or the same values when using gl.Pointcoord?

Comment: If a point has a size of more the 1.0 (e.g. by setting `gl_PointSize=5.0.`) then the fragment shader is executed more then once, becaus the "point" takes palce over more than one fragment. The depth of this fragments can be set individually.